# A schedule running multiple hobs sequentially

Tags: dagster

I am trying to create a schedule that will fit my model to sensor data every week. Now, I have about 100 sensors to analyse and the model architecture and parameters are the same. I have a job which can analyse a single sensor and it works fine. However, I do not want to create a separate schedule for every sensor. It would be nice for the same schedule to dynamically create the jobs for each sensor. Is there such a mechanism in Dagster?

Additionally, I would like the jobs to then execute sequentially (due to the current computation constraints). Is it possible to create such a schedule setup in Dagster? Essentially, I want to run the same job  with different inputs in a sequential fashion.

So, at the moment, I have the following schedule setup:

```
@schedule(
    name="train_job",
    cron_schedule="0 19 * * *",
    job=train__job,
)
def train_schedule():
    with open(file_relative_path(__file__, "sensor_train.yaml")) as f:
        sensor_config = yaml.safe_load(f)

    with open(file_relative_path(__file__, "overrides__train.yaml")) as f:
        base_config = yaml.safe_load(f)

    base_config.update(sensor_config)

    tags = {"trigger_prediction": "true"}

    return RunRequest(run_key=None, run_config=base_config, tags=tags)
```

So, basically here I am performing some config overrides and running a single job. Essentially, I would like to do some overrides for each sensor and launch a job for each of them in a sequential fashion. I am essentially looking to have a synchronous loop around the whole thing where I can configure the inputs.